# Шифрование файла сертификатом электронной подписи (который дается Минцифрой России)

Tags: python, openssl

Имеются вот такие сертификаты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Формат расширения сертификата .cer, кодирование (если не ошибаюсь с этим словом) ASN.1, информацию вытащил из сертификата через код:

```
def get_certificate_format(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        der = f.read()
        try:
            x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, der)
            return 'ASN.1'
        except OpenSSL.crypto.Error:
            pass
        
        try:
            x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, der)
            return 'PEM'
        except OpenSSL.crypto.Error:
            pass
        
        return 'Unknown'
```

Не получается вытащить публичный ключ, если правильно понимаю, им шифруются файлы.
Файл должен шифроваться с методом кодирования DER и расширением шифрованного файла .enc

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-нибудь способ зашифровать сертификатом файл при помощи python. Даже вытащить публичный ключ проблема:

```
import OpenSSL.crypto
import glob
folder_path = r"F:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР"
file_paths = glob.glob(f"{folder_path}/**/*.cer", recursive=True)
for file_path in file_paths:
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        cert_data = file.read()
        cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, cert_data)
    public_key = cert.get_pubkey().to_cryptography_key()
    print(public_key)
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Python\Flask\t.py", line 9, in <module>
    public_key = cert.get_pubkey().to_cryptography_key()
  File "C:\Users\shirshov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 1239, in get_pubkey
    _raise_current_error()
  File "C:\Users\shirshov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 57, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('digital envelope routines', '', 'decode error')]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, не оформляйте код python как html script snippet

Comment: @strawdog, хорошо. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с сертификатами и ключами ГОСТ нужно воспользоваться криптопровайдером с поддержкой gost-2012.

Самое простое КриптоПро и их библиотека https://docs.cryptopro.ru/cades/pycades

Установка на Linux довольно простая, описана в документации

Например проверка подписи

```
import pycades
from asn1crypto import x509

signature = b'data.....'

signedData = pycades.SignedData()
signedData.ContentEncoding = pycades.CADESCOM_BASE64_TO_BINARY
res = signedData.VerifyCades(signature, pycades.CADESCOM_CADES_BES)

signer =  signedData.Signers.Item(1)
cert = signer.Certificate.Export(pycades.CADESCOM_BASE64_TO_BINARY)
```

Тут достали сертификат и можно посмотреть что там внутри, уже без КриптоПро

```
cert = x509.Certificate.load(cert)
  
subject =  dict(cert.subject.native )
oidmap = {
  "OGRNIP": "1.2.643.100.5",
  "INNLE":  "1.2.643.100.4",
  "SNILS":  "1.2.643.100.3",
  "OGRN":   "1.2.643.100.1",
  "INN":    "1.2.643.3.131.1.1",
}

for k,v in oidmap.items():
    subject[k]=subject.pop(v, None)

print(subject)
```

Второе по сложности https://github.com/gost-engine/engine и стандартные библиотеки на базе openssl. В некоторых достаточно подгрузить gost-engine через файл конфигурации или переменные окружения, а некоторые придется пересобрать из исходников.

Comment: Спасибо большое, нашел форум https://forum.mista.ru/topic.php?id=877912 где говорят про Ваш 1 вариант (если правильно их понял). но, ни один из вариантов не помог. Другой вариант, есть какой то древний VBScript и чего то там дальше...))) буду дальше копать. А так Ваш вариант приму и закрою вопрос

Comment: Вам похоже надо для виндовс. сейчас нет под рукой чтоб пройти установку по шагам...

Comment: @МихаилШиршов добавил пример как распарсить сертификат.

Comment: вытаскивать информацию из сертификата я примерно научился, но не дает вытащить инфу о публичном ключе (как я понимаю, им нужно шифровать), выдает ошибку не правильный формат файла или чего то там еще (не помню). но нашел другой способ (через subprocess), пробую его сделать. смысл такой. открыть программу Такском-КриптоЛайн, загрузить Excel файлы и далее шифровать. Кода еще нет, но сама идея только)) код как вытаскиваю инфу из сертификата скину ответом на свой вопрос

Comment: да с ключами работать можно только через криптопро и прочие российские ЦСП

Answer (score 0):

Вытаскиваю инфу из сертификата:

```
import OpenSSL.crypto
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import glob

folder_path = r"F:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР"
file_paths = glob.glob(f"{folder_path}/**/*.cer", recursive=True)

data = []

# в командной строке certutil -dump "F:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР\Шатки ключ\ОТДЕЛ_ЗЕМЕЛЬНЫХ_И_ИМУЩЕСТВЕННЫХ_ОТНОШЕНИЙ_АДМИНИСТРАЦИИ_ШАТКОВСКОГО.cer"

def get_certificate_format(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        der = f.read()
        try:
            x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, der)
            return 'ASN.1'
        except OpenSSL.crypto.Error:
            pass
        
        try:
            x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, der)
            return 'PEM'
        except OpenSSL.crypto.Error:
            pass
        
        return 'Unknown'

for file_path in file_paths:
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        der = f.read()
        x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, der)
        not_before = x509.get_notBefore()
        not_after = x509.get_notAfter()

        date_format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ"
        not_before_date = datetime.strptime(not_before.decode("utf-8"), date_format)
        not_after_date = datetime.strptime(not_after.decode("utf-8"), date_format)
    
        subject_dict = dict(map(lambda component: (component[0].decode('utf-8'), component[1].decode('utf-8')), x509.get_subject().get_components()))
        format = get_certificate_format(file_path)
        serial_number = x509.get_serial_number()
        serial_number_str = serial_number.to_bytes((serial_number.bit_length() + 7) // 8, byteorder="big").hex()

        URI = x509.get_extension(6) # Списки аннулированных сертификатов
        

        data.append({
        'file_path': file_path,
        **subject_dict,
        'not_before_date': not_before_date,
        'not_after_date': not_after_date,
        'format_file_certificate':format,
        'serial_number': serial_number_str
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

column_names = list(x509.get_subject().get_components())
df = df.reindex(columns=[component[0].decode('utf-8') for component in column_names] + ['file_path'] + 
                ['not_before_date'] + ['not_after_date'] + ['format_file_certificate'] + ['serial_number'])
df.to_excel(r'F:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР\certificate.xlsx', index=False)
```

---

Вытаскиваю инфу из списка аннулированных сертификатов:

```
import OpenSSL.crypto
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl

crl_file = r"F:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР\ucfk_2022.crl"
excel_file = r"F:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР\отозванные_сертификаты.xlsx"

reason_date = {'Cessation Of Operation':'Сертификат более не нужен для целей, которых он выдавался, но нет причины полагать, что секретный ключ скомпрометирован',
                'No reason specified':'Причина неизвестна',
                'Privilege Withdrawn':'Привилегии, предоставленные субъекту сертификата, были отозваны',
                'Superseded':'Сертификат заменен другим, но нет причины полагать, что секретный ключ скомпрометирован',
                'CA Compromise':'Компрометация Центра Сертификации',
                'Key Compromise':'Компрометация ключей',
                'Affiliation Changed':'Имя пользователя или другая информация в сертификате изменена, но нет причины полагать, что секретный ключ скомпрометирован',
                'AA Compromise':'Известно или подозревается, что закрытый ключ субъекта сертификата был скомпрометирован. Это относится только к сертификатам атрибута authority (AA)'}

def get_crl_characteristics(crl_file, excel_file):
    with open(crl_file, 'rb') as file:
        crl_data = file.read()

    crl = OpenSSL.crypto.load_crl(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, crl_data)
    date_format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ"
    revoked_certificates = crl.get_revoked()
    
    if revoked_certificates:
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        worksheet = workbook.active
        headers = ["Серийный номер", "Время отзыва", "Причина отзыва", "Пояснения"]
        worksheet.append(headers)

        for certificate in revoked_certificates:
            ser = certificate.get_serial()
            fg = certificate.get_rev_date()
            date = datetime.strptime(fg.decode("utf-8"), date_format)
            reason = certificate.get_reason()
            if reason is not None:
                reason_text_1 = reason.decode("utf-8")
                reason_text = reason_date.get(reason.decode("utf-8"))
            else:
                reason_text = None
            
            data_row = [ser, date, reason_text_1, reason_text]
            worksheet.append(data_row)
        workbook.save(excel_file)


get_crl_characteristics(crl_file, excel_file)
```

---

Шифрование файлов через программу Такском-КриптоЛайн. Код паршивый но вроде работает... (перед запуском, раскладку клавиатуры ставлю на английский). Директория сертификатов шифрования выглядит примерно так "F:\gos\50\ser.cer", где "\50" номер района в котором лежит свой сертификат. Функции setCyrillicLayout() и setEngLayout() нашел [тут](https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread1685571.html):

```
import subprocess
import glob
import os
import time
import pyautogui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32com.client
import win32api

mo = {'Ардатовский муниципальный округ':'51','Балахнинский муниципальный округ':'1716','Богородский муниципальный округ':'2423',
'Большеболдинский муниципальный округ':'58','Большемурашкинский муниципальный округ':'31','Бутурлинский муниципальный округ':'44',
'Вадский муниципальный округ':'42','Варнавинский муниципальный округ':'6','Вачский муниципальный округ':'36',
'Ветлужский муниципальный округ':'1','Вознесенский муниципальный округ':'54','Володарский муниципальный округ':'22',
'Воскресенский муниципальный округ':'11','Гагинский муниципальный округ':'49','городской округ г. Арзамас':'4041',
'городской округ г. Бор':'1920','городской округ Воротынский':'28','городской округ г. Выкса':'5253',
'городской округ г. Дзержинск':'21','городской округ г. Кулебаки':'3839','городской округ Навашинский':'37',
'городской округ г. Нижний Новгород':'18','городской округ г. Первомайск':'56','городской округ Перевозский':'43',
'городской округ г. Саров':'60','городской округ Семеновский':'12','городской округ Сокольский':'7',
'городской округ г. Чкаловск':'13','городской округ г. Шахунья':'3','Городецкий муниципальный округ':'15',
'Дальнеконстантиновский муниципальный округ':'32','Дивеевский муниципальный округ':'55','Княгининский муниципальный округ':'30',
'Ковернинский муниципальный округ':'8','Краснобаковский муниципальный округ':'9','Краснооктябрьский муниципальный округ':'47',
'Кстовский муниципальный округ':'2625','Лукояновский муниципальный округ':'57','Лысковский муниципальный округ':'27',
'Павловский муниципальный округ':'3433','Пильнинский муниципальный округ':'46','Починковский муниципальный округ':'59',
'Сергачский муниципальный округ':'45','Сеченовский муниципальный округ':'48','Сосновский муниципальный округ':'35',
'Спасский муниципальный округ':'29','Тонкинский муниципальный округ':'4','Тоншаевский муниципальный округ':'2',
'Уренский муниципальный округ':'5','Шарангский муниципальный округ':'10','Шатковский муниципальный округ':'50',}

#Переключить на рус.
def setCyrillicLayout():
    window_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    result = win32api.SendMessage(window_handle, 0x0050, 0, 0x04190419)
    return(result)
#Переключить на англ.
def setEngLayout():
    window_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    result = win32api.SendMessage(window_handle, 0x0050, 0, 0x04090409)
    return(result)

takskom_path = r"C:\Taxcom\CryptoLine\CryptoLine.exe"

folder_path_xlsx = r"C:\Users\shirshov\Desktop\Kladr"
file_paths_xlsx = glob.glob(f"{folder_path_xlsx}/**/*.xlsx", recursive=True)

folder_path_cer = r"F:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР"
file_paths_cer = glob.glob(f"{folder_path_cer}/**/*.cer", recursive=True)


# Добавление файлов в список
for file_path in file_paths_xlsx:
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    file_name_get = mo.get(os.path.splitext(file_name)[0])
    subprocess.Popen([takskom_path, file_path])
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('down')
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Такском - КриптоЛайн версия 1.5")
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click(991, 85)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click(1094, 445)
    pyautogui.click(1094, 445)
    time.sleep(2)
    setEngLayout()
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
    path_cer = r"F:\gos\{}\ser.cer".format(str(file_name_get))
    shell.SendKeys(path_cer)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click(1317, 699)
    pyautogui.click(1026, 671)
    time.sleep(2)
```